# How to put a includegraphics near (at the right or the left of) a tabular in Latex?

Tags: image, latex

In latex, I would like to put my includegraphics at the left of my tabular and having the text written after the tabular popping in a new paragraph (not at the right of my image}.

Didn't succeed with wrapfig package...

```latex
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{bla.jpg}
\bigbreak
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
a1 & a2
b1 & b2
\end{tabular}
\bigbreak
Some text here....
```

At the moment they are following each other.

Comment: Can you draw a sketch how the result should look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not really understand your question. In TeX, images or tables are boxes (like a character) and just putting them on the same line (without a paragraph break) achieves the desired effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{monalisa}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
a1 & a2\\
b1 & b2
\end{tabular}
\bigbreak
Some text here....
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is that alignment is weird. There are many ways to control box alignment with respect to the baseline. For tabular, there is an optional argument t, b or c, that specifies if table is globally aligned on its top, bottom or center. For the image, you can wrap it in a minipage (or parbox) and specify the box alignment in an identical way (but there are many other  solutions to do that).

Here is a way to center boxes. To have a finer alignment, you can use a raisebox.

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{4cm}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{monalisa}
\end{minipage}
\begin{tabular}[c]{c|c}
a1 & a2\\
b1 & b2
\end{tabular}
\bigbreak
Some text here....
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the first good answer based on `minipage`s, you could nest two `tabular`s and adjust the vertical alignment using `\parbox[c]{}{}`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \noindent\parbox[c]{.6\hsize}{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{bla.jpg}} & %
  \noindent\parbox[c]{\hsize}{%
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
      a1 & a2\\
      b1 & b2
    \end{tabular}}
\end{tabular}

\bigbreak

Some text here....

\end{document}
```